# How to add request parameters for a postman request in pre-script request

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I want to add query parameters for my request in postman through the pre-request script. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you expand on the reason for wanting to do this, please?

Comment: i want to add it in a collection's pre request script instead of manually adding for all APIs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something basic like this could be used in the Collection `Pre-request Script`:

```
pm.request.url.query.add({key: 'test', value: '1234'})
```

Answer (score 4):

A more recent property exposed in Postman's pre-request scripts is the `addQueryParams` method.

To add a single param:

```js
pm.request.addQueryParams("id=123")
```

To add multiple params:

```js
pm.request.addQueryParams([
  "id=123",
  "name=Homer",
  "city=Springfield"
])
```

You can be super verbose as well:

```js
pm.request.addQueryParams("id=123")
pm.request.addQueryParams("name=Homer")
pm.request.addQueryParams("city=Springfield")
```

An easy way to test out pre-request scripts is to use the Postman get url: https://postman-echo.com/get